# Git tag inside post-receive hook

Tags: bash, git, laravel, shell

To create i simple auto deploy script,i have created a post-receive hook on my git like below :

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_DIR="/srv/git/test.git"
TARGET="/srv/www/laravel"
BRANCH="master"

while read oldrev newrev ref
do
        # only checking out the master (or whatever branch you would like to deploy)
        if [[ $ref = refs/heads/$BRANCH ]] ;
        then
                echo "Ref $ref received. Deploying ${BRANCH} branch to ${TARGET}"
                git --work-tree=$TARGET --git-dir=$GIT_DIR checkout -f
                #expecting value from git describe --tag like v0.4-45-g0a0b538 
                pushd $TARGET
                echo {tag}
                php artisan make:version {tag} 
                popd
        else
                echo "Ref $ref received. Doing nothing: only the ${BRANCH} branch may be deployed on this server."
        fi
done
```

However, I cannot find a way to get the printed value from `git describe --tag` like `v0.4-45-g0a0b538`to my {tag} from my bare repository.

`php artisan make:version` is a command to save the `{tag}` to my .env file which later on, it will display to my web page.

I wonder if there is a way to get the latest tag every time i pushed on master branch and save it in my .env file.

Edited :

I manage to get the `git describe --tags` output from my bare repository but i  think it is a little bit messy since i have to duplicate my get worktree command.

```
git --work-tree=$TARGET --git-dir=$GIT_DIR checkout -f                                                 
pushd $TARGET > /dev/null                                                                              
php artisan iapms:version $(git --work-tree=$TARGET --git-dir=$GIT_DIR describe --tags)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbash%5D+get+command+output

Comment: i don`t think its duplicate. My goal is to get the git describe --tags output from my bare repository.